# перекрытие фона другим, наезжающим на него, фоном

Tags: javascript, html, css

чтобы стало понятнее, вот пример фона, которого хотелось бы достичь:http://www.south-stream-transport.com/
Подскажите, как можно реализовать что-то похожее, но без движения верхнего фона из стороны в сторону проезжающих блоков или с ними, без разницы, буду премного благодарен)

Comment: наверное стоит копать в сторону паралакса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не очень понятно, что конкретно вы хотите достичь, но как я понял (могу ошибаться) имеется в виду маскирование

т.е. у вас есть задний фон и маска (которую можно как угодно трансформировать), в результате складывается впечатление, что задний фон меняет форму

почитайте про маскирование с css, javascript

http://htmlbook.ru/blog/maskirovanie-v-css

https://habr.com/ru/post/164409/

https://habr.com/ru/post/190246/

и т.д.

вот тут анимации с маскированием:

https://speckyboy.com/css-svg-canvas-masks/